# SPUser have logon into Site Collection?

Tags: 2010, site-collection, login, spuser, token

Possible to loop through all Site Collection Users and check if they have ever logon into the Site Collection and when?
db table dbo.UserInfo tokens info can be useful?

this [script](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/dd378867%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can retrieve the last domain logon, but is not enough.

Update: isActive flag in dbo.UserInfo set to 1 when user hits the site for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSScript that access SQL table UserInfo, and for each site retrieves the users and according to the following metadata:

- tp_IsActive (is 1, account active)
- tp_ExternalToken and tp_ExternalTokenlastUpdated (if null, user never access)

Answer (score 1):

similar question answered here: looks like its not as easy as it may sound!

[Getting SPUser Last login date / time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62104/getting-spuser-last-login-date-time)

Comment: I had read it before, actually is not really answered but it's a good point. Thanks for the aid.